# Close a MSI file handle after being downloaded from a website

Tags: vb.net, vsto, ioexception

I have a vsto add-in for outlook. There is a code where I download a MSI file from a website:

```
Public Sub DownloadMsiFile()
    Try
        Dim url As String = "https://www.website.com/ol.msi"
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;")
        If File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\ol.msi") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\ol.msi")
        End If
        wc.DownloadFile(url, My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\ol.msi")
        wc.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("File couldn't be downloaded: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And then I get the MSI version using the following function:

```
Function GetMsiVersion() As String
    Try
        Dim oInstaller As WindowsInstaller.Installer
        Dim oDb As WindowsInstaller.Database
        Dim oView As WindowsInstaller.View
        Dim oRecord As WindowsInstaller.Record
        Dim sSQL As String
        oInstaller = CType(CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer"), WindowsInstaller.Installer)
        DownloadMsiFile()
        If File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\ol.msi") Then
            oDb = oInstaller.OpenDatabase(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\ol.msi", 0)
            sSQL = "SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property`='ProductVersion'"
            oView = oDb.OpenView(sSQL)
            oView.Execute()
            oRecord = oView.Fetch
            Return oRecord.StringData(1).ToString()
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("File couldn't be accessed: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

And then I do the comparison with the current dll version to see if there is a need to download a newer version or not:

```
Public Sub CheckOLUpdates()
    Dim remoteVersion As String = GetMsiVersion()
    Dim installedVersion As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteVersion) Then
        Try
            If String.Compare(installedVersion, remoteVersion) < 0 Then
                Dim Result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("A newer version is available for download, do you want to download it now?", "OL", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                If Result = 1 Then
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com/update")
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("You have the latest version installed!", "OL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

This works pretty well if this ran once. However if I try again to check for update, I would get the following error which happens while trying to delete the file in DownloadMsiFile() :

> The process cannot access the file %temp%\ol.msi because it is being used by another process

If I use the sysinternals handle.exe utility to check the handles on this file I get the outlook process having a handle lock on this file:

```
handle.exe %temp%\ol.msi
Nthandle v4.30 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

OUTLOOK.EXE        pid: 25964  type: File          4FC8: %temp%\ol.msi
```

I was wondering how can I close the handle to avoid this error? Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I have to do to close the handle. I have added the following lines after opening the MSI file:

```
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oRecord)
            oView.Close()
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oView)
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oDb)
            oRecord = Nothing
            oView = Nothing
            oDb = Nothing
```

So my final code looked like the following:

```
Function GetMsiVersion() As String
    Try
        Dim oInstaller As WindowsInstaller.Installer
        Dim oDb As WindowsInstaller.Database
        Dim oView As WindowsInstaller.View
        Dim oRecord As WindowsInstaller.Record
        Dim sSQL As String
        Dim Version As String
        oInstaller = CType(CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer"), WindowsInstaller.Installer)
        DownloadMsiFile()
        If File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\ol.msi") Then
            oDb = oInstaller.OpenDatabase(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\ol.msi", 0)
            sSQL = "SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property`='ProductVersion'"
            oView = oDb.OpenView(sSQL)
            oView.Execute()
            oRecord = oView.Fetch
            Version = oRecord.StringData(1).ToString()
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oRecord)
            oView.Close()
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oView)
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oDb)
            oRecord = Nothing
            oView = Nothing
            oDb = Nothing
        Else
            Version = Nothing
        End If
        Return Version
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("File couldn't be accessed: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Fixed my problem of the msi file being locked while the application was active/open!